# model has two attributes that belong to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, model-associations

I have a model as follows:

```
 Greeting

  belongs_to :icon
  belongs_to :icon, :foreign_key => :user_icon
```

I need to save the icon_id and also the user_icon id in the case I don't have a registered user.

Is this correct? Will I be able to access the icon by doing the following:

```
@greeting.icon.name
@greeting.user_icon.name
```

I want to improve this question so let me explain it better:

I want to save two objects from the same model in another model.

So Greeting belongs to Icon but I will have two fields in the Greetings table for foreign keys from the Icons table but labeled differently.

I call one foreign key attribute icon_id and the other user_icon_id.

To do this is the following correct:

```
Greeting

belongs_to :icon
belongs_to :icon, foreign_key => :user_icon_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost correct, you need something like this:

```
belongs_to :icon
belongs_to :user_icon, :class_name => "Icon", foreign_key => :user_icon_id
```

If you change the name of the field in a `has_one, has_many or belongs_to` association in such a way that Rails can't convert it into a model name, you need to tell Rails which model you actually mean, hence the `:class_name`.

Comment: Thanks very much SHorks for your answer and excellent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You need

```
belongs_to :user_icon, :foreign_key => :user_icon
```

If you want to have a greeting.user_icon accessor using the foreign key user icon in your database.